# Replacing cell values from a SpatRaster to another binary stacked SpatRaster under certain conditions in R (terra Package)

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have a binary stacked SpatRaster ***bstacked_fht*** whose 25 layers correspond to presence/absence data for different forest habitat types. Instead of having only values 0 and 1, I want to replace the value 1 with the respective pixel of another SpatRaster ***vit_dec*** only when the value is 0.25. In other words, replace the values only when bstacked_fht[[i]] = 1 and vit_dec = 0.25. Both layers have also NULL values.

```
print(bstacked_fht)
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 2370, 2513, 25  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
# extent      : 280329.8, 531629.8, 5578461, 5815461  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:25832) 
# sources     : spat_nx7E84x54c8tnTN_24884.tif  
# spat_nx7E84x54c8tnTN_24884.tif  (17 layers) 
# spat_nx7E84x54c8tnTN_24884.tif  (7 layers) 
# names       : class_1, class_3, class_4, class_5, class_6, class_7, ... 
# min values  :       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0, ... 
# max values  :       1,       1,       1,       1,       1,       1, ... 


freq(bstacked_fht)
# layer value count
# 1      1     0 91763
# 2      1     1   524
# 3      2     0 88677
# 4      2     1  3610
# 5      3     0 92281
# 6      3     1     6
# 7      4     0 92281
# 8      4     1     6
# 9      5     0 91933
# 10     5     1   354
# 11     6     0 80878
# 12     6     1 11409
# 13     7     0 92106
# 14     7     1   181
# 15     8     0 89741
# 16     8     1  2546
# 17     9     0 92268
# 18     9     1    19
# 19    10     0 90569
# 20    10     1  1718
# 21    11     0 92245
# 22    11     1    42
# 23    12     0 92141
# 24    12     1   146
# 25    13     0 55803
# 26    13     1 36484
# 27    14     0 92280
# 28    14     1     7
# 29    15     0 69071
# 30    15     1 23216
# 31    16     0 91796
# 32    16     1   491
# 33    17     0 85216
# 34    17     1  7071
# 35    18     0 92105
# 36    18     1   182
# 37    19     0 91956
# 38    19     1   331
# 39    20     0 89634
# 40    20     1  2653
# 41    21     0 91160
# 42    21     1  1127
# 43    22     0 92286
# 44    22     1     1
# 45    23     0 92131
# 46    23     1   156
# 47    24     0 92282
# 48    24     1     5
# 49    25     0 92285
# 50    25     1     2

print(vit_dec)
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 2370, 2513, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
# extent      : 280329.8, 531629.8, 5578461, 5815461  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:25832) 
# source(s)   : memory
# name        : vitality_highly_decreased_25832 
# min value   :                            0.00 
# max value   :                            0.25 

freq(vit_dec)
#   layer value  count
# 1     1     0 186034
```

I've attempted various approaches with no success. Something like:

```
function(bstacked_fht, vit_dec, thresh = 0.5, vit_dec_thresh = 0.20) {
    result <- list()
    
  for (i in 1:25) {
        layer <- bstacked_fht[[i]]
        
        higher <- layer > thresh & vit_layer > vit_dec_thresh
        layer[higher] <- vit_layer[higher]
        
        result[[i]] <- layer
    }
    
    names(result) <- names(bstacked_fht)
    return(result)
}
```

or

```
for (i in 1:25) {
    a_layer <- bstacked_fht[[i]]
    
    a_layer[] <- ifelse(a_layer[] > 0.5 & vit_dec[] > 0.2, vit_dec[], a_layer[])
    
    bstacked_fht[[i]] <- a_layer
}
```

Perhaps this isn't feasible in a binary stacked raster where only binary values are possible. I'm running low on ideas.
Do you have any suggestions on how to do it? Should I convert my bstacked_fht into another type of object?

Comment: Perhaps add `freq(vit_dec)` above, along with other rabbit holes you tried but those failed...

Answer (score 0):

Don't have your data, but perhaps `mask` is what you're looking for

```
library(terra) 
set.seed(42)
present = array(sample(c(0,1), 216L, replace = TRUE), dim = c(6,6,6))
present_r = rast(present)
sick = rast(matrix(sample(c(0, 0.25), 36L, replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.97, 0.03)), ncol =6)) #prob approx your present/sick
#plot(sick) - just to check we got one or so cells under sample probs
present_r_masked = mask(present_r, sick, maskvalues = 0.25, updatevalue = 0.25)
```

[image]

Perhaps. Continuing (and wishing away `prioritizr` & others over and above `terra` operations).

As I interpret your vit_dec, these 186034 cells are fixed locations of degradation (however arrived at) and such fixity is essentially irrespective of what 'class' or 'category' (be it spa, or state forest) that (may) also exists there on a == 1 basis.

There is a problem there. Saying, for instance, 'spa doesn't == 1', because there isn't a spa there now, might lead to proposing the siting of a spa there (or other uses in a land use planning sense), even though it is already an area under (some kind of) pressure. Does a further use mitigate the degradation in that area?

This is overly long way to say I disagree with 'its only degraded' on layer.x if x == 1 exists on layer.x. Nor does layer.x == 1 and is.degraded == 0.25 on that cell show causality... Enough on that.

As to `terra::mask(`, there is no reason to `mask = bstacked_fht * vit_dec` in place of `mask = vit_dec` unless you what to drive out recognition of degradation in that layer as bstacked_fht with a cell value of 0 will necessarily return zero in that cell. It would also account for the plots where you are not seeing 0.25 as a cell value and others where you are. So give `,mask = vit_dec,` a try.

Again, I don't have your data, but I've looked at your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this way:

`mask_bstacked <- bstacked_fht == 1
 mask_vit <- vit_dec == 0.25
 modified_bstacked_fht <- mask(bstacked_fht, mask_bstacked * mask_vit, updatevalue = 0.25)` but when I run `freq(modified_bstacked_fht)` I still get only values 0 and 1 although when I plot it I get some strange plot with 0,1 and 0.25 values in some cases. Is it possible that with objects created with the function `binary_stack()` you can't have more than two values?

Comment: This (https://github.com/fabiofebocastelli/systematic-conservation-planning/blob/main/Scenario1) is the link to my repository where everything is explained.

Comment: `prioritizr::binary_stack(` is 'simply' a wrapper around `terra::segregate(` that creates, seemingly, a new separate layer for each categorical class, so a single layer with 5 classes is passed in, 5 layers, one for each class comes out under `c(`, presumably as this is how `terra` approaches stacks. This says that the 'result' of binary_stack or segregate assigns rather that restricts to binary values (which makes segregate similar, though different from mask) more later, have to walk the dog..

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, Chris.  What I am considering here as highly damaged forests are forests that have been completely cleared out by natural calamities. I want to produce a scenario where the state decides to expand the strictly protected areas up to a fixed amount of hectares to meet 10% of forest strictly protected (see budget=52351), trying to include as many different forest habitat types (fht) and Natura2000 sites as possible. Our idea is to exclude the highly damaged forests due to their low ecological value (there is no forest there anymore).

Comment: To give higher priority to healthy stands, a strategy could be to give higher value to those planning units (cells) that correspond to healthy forests for each fht layer. In this way when a relative target for conservation features has been set (e.g., include the 50% of all fht), the solution should give higher priority to those cells with higher values because it will be the cheapest solution - if I have  5 cells of value 1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 (sum=2) and each cells has the same cost as in my case, and my relative target is  0.5 (namely=1), the solution should pick the first cell.

Comment: Because you get the same result at a lower cost. That's why I'm trying to assign the vit_dec values to all my fht layers. I hope now it more clear.

Comment: The aspiration of Natura2000 is to fill the gaps between supportive ecologies in addition to end points. This quasi-cooridor approach underpins the species protection outcomes and necessarily would include high cost highly degraded gap areas. One could point to the Chernobyl experiment for example of the (rapid?) benefits of human exclusion, but further such experiments are ill-advised. Could you, as a matter of data, post to git hub the `vit_dec`.